# d3.js color from Json on data change

Tags: d3.js

Using this as an example: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/treemap.html

I am trying to make color of the rectangles in the tree map dependent on which data is visualized. The example lets you draw the tree map by size or by count. I've added two variables to each entry json file, "cola" and "colb". Each is just a color.

When the graphic is first drawn it is sorted based on size and uses cola to color the rectangles. I have no problem making the map redraw using count rather than size. What I can't figure out is how to get it to use colb instead of cola.

Here's part of the code. This is where the color is first picked.

```
  cell.append("svg:rect")
      .attr("width", function(d) { return d.dx - 1; })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy - 1; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.cola; });
```

Here's the change function.

```
  d3.select("select").on("change", function() {
    treemap.value(this.value == "size" ? size : count).nodes(root);
    if (treemap.value(this.value == "size")) {
    cell.append("svg:rect").style("fill", function(d) {return d.cola; });
     }
    else {
     cell.append("svg:rect").style("fill", function(d) {return d.colb; });
    };
    zoom(node);

  });
});
```

Still trying to figure out d3.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use some kind of variable in your code that specifies which color you want to use (based on the state of your select control):

```
var cola = (d3.select("select").node().value == "size");
```

and

```
cell.append("svg:rect")
    .attr("width", function(d) { return d.dx - 1; })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy - 1; })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return cola ? d.cola : d.colb; });
```

Then, the select button can toggle this variable:

```
d3.select("select").on("change", function() {
  treemap.value(this.value == "size" ? size : count).nodes(root);
  cola = (this.value == "size");
  zoom(node);
});
```

Make sure to update the fill style in your zoom function as well:

```
  t.select("rect")
      .attr("width", function(d) { return kx * d.dx - 1; })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return ky * d.dy - 1; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return cola ? d.cola : d.colb; });
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. I also had completely missed the updating in the zoom function too. 

Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the line:

```js
 if (treemap.value(this.value == "size")) ...
```

It should read:

```js
if (this.value == "size") ...
```

Also, you probably mean `cell.selectAll('rect').style(...)` instead of `cell.append('rect').style(...)` inside the `if-then-else` body. However, I cannot say for sure without seeing rest of the code.

Comment: Thanks for help. I ended up just using a variable to specify the color based on the state of the select control.